# Flutter: Comparing variables from function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to compare the results from functions which get random elements from a list to ensure that the elements are not the same. My code gives different elements most of the time, however occasionally results in the same element for player1 and player2. I assume that this is because when player1 is called in the player2gen function it generates a new variable. I am not sure how to get around this.

My code:

```
player1gen(List players) {
  return players[Random().nextInt(players.length)].toString();
}

String get player1 => player1gen(players);

player2gen(List players) {
  String player2comp = players[Random().nextInt(players.length)].toString();
  while (player2comp == player1) {
    String player2comp = players[Random().nextInt(players.length)].toString();
    if (player2comp != player1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return player2comp;
}

String get player2 => player2gen(players);
```

Comment: Do you always want a new `player1` whenever you use it, or do you want just two different players that you can keep using? I feel like the former is quite counterintuitive as you can only have access to your player once.

Comment: I always want a new player1 when it is called, same with player2. Each round needs to have different players.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive approach to get random number that is not generated already. Maintain a global variable something like to this , to store previously generated random numbers.

```
   //Global Variable
       late String player1;
    
        player1gen(List players) {
          player1 =  players[Random().nextInt(players.length)].toString();
          return player1;
        }
        
        String get player1 => player1gen(players);
        
        player2gen(List players) {
            String player2comp = players[Random().nextInt(players.length)].toString();
        if(player2comp == player1)
          return player2comp;
        else 
          return player2gen(players); //Recursive function. It will run provide different number that is not equal to player 1 
        }
        
        String get player2 => player2gen(players);
```

Comment: This did not help

Comment: Could you please tell whats happening?

Comment: Same as before, the items for player1 and player2 are the same sometimes.